# VB for Excel - How do you control the number of empty rows between sets of data in a sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I am trying to print specific columns from a sheet that has data clustered  along the rows. Sorry about the size but the table below shows how the data has it's name in the first column and related data is in column 2 and 3. I already eliminated the unnecessary columns prior to this point.

The important part is how the number of rows in a cluster and the number of empty rows between the clusters varies randomly.

| Header | Header | Header |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DataLine1 | DataLine1 | DataLine1 |
|  | DataLine2 | DataLine2 |
|  |  | DataLine3 |
|  |  | DataLine4 |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
| DataLine7 | DataLine7 | DataLine7 |
|  |  | DataLine8 |
|  |  | DataLine9 |
|  |  | DataLine10 |
|  |  |  |
| DataLine12 | DataLine12 | DataLine12 |
|  |  | DataLine13 |
|  |  | DataLine14 |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
| DataLine19 | DataLine19 | DataLine19 |
|  |  | DataLine20 |
|  |  | DataLine21 |
|  |  | DataLine22 |
|  |  |  |
| DataLine24 | DataLine24 | DataLine24 |
|  | DataLine25 | DataLine25 |
|  |  | DataLine26 |
|  |  | DataLine27 |

There's hundreds of rows of this stuff.

This both looks bad when printed and will make it hard for me to program where the page breaks go (keeping the clusters's integrity on a page). So, I want to programmatically edit the worksheet to make each gap between clusters a gap of three empty rows. That will let me set the page breaks at the middle of a three row gap, to look nicer on the printout.

Trouble is, I think I'm out of my depth here. I think I need to set up three (more?) different counters and have the whole Sub restart with each addition or deletion of a row... Some examples do that, but how should I handle the resetting without wasting gads of cycles of checking rows?

If anyone could point me in the right direction for code examples or a solid plan of attack, it would be amazing.

(Or tell me that I'm nuts to think about solving the page breaks that way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scan up the sheet removing multiple empty rows leaving one. Then scan down the sheet adding manual page breaks at the empty lines as required. Adjust MAXROWS to fit page.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub mymacro()

    Const MAXROWS = 40

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long, r As Long, n As Integer
    Dim break As Long, count As Long

    Set ws = Sheet1
    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    ' remove existing page breaks if any
    ws.Cells.PageBreak = xlPageBreakNone

    ' delete all except 1 empty row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For r = lastrow To 2 Step -1
        If Len(ws.Cells(r, 3)) = 0 And Len(ws.Cells(r - 1, 3)) = 0 Then
            ws.Rows(r).Delete
        End If
    Next

    ' add manual page breaks
    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    count = 0
    For r = 1 To lastrow
        count = count + 1
        If Len(ws.Cells(r, 3)) = 0 Then
            break = r
        End If

        If count > MAXROWS Then
            ws.Rows(break + 1).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
            count = r - break
            n = n + 1
        End If

    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox n & " psge breaks inserted"
End Sub
```